# select only tuples where second column always has same value

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a similar table to this one

```
ID | CountryID
1 | 22
1 | 22
2 | 19
3 | 0
3 | 14
3 | 18
3 | 21
3 | 22
3 | 23
4 | 19
5 | 9
5 | 9
6 | 14
```

and I want to group by the first ID column but select only rows, where the CountryID has the same value throughout an ID. The resulting table should look like

```
ID | CountryID
1 | 22
2 | 19
4 | 19
5 | 9
6 | 14
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following query should work:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(CountryID)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(CountryID) = MAX(CountryID)
```

Comment: This will fail in case when the value which gets repeated is not min/max like (7,13),(7,12),(7,11),(7,12). If I am understanding correctly this should select (7,12) as well.

Comment: Yes, though we insert row with `(4,22)`

Comment: @CoderofCode The OP says `where the CountryID has the same value throughout an ID`, which I believe contradicts your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, count(distinct CountryID)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(distinct CountryID)=1
```

Comment: Your query returns a count in the second column, and not a CountryID as requested by the OP.